# Python | Selecting rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I'm utterly lost on the following. I have a test Dataframe filled with tweets and metadata. Now, under certain conditions (say, I want to select all retweets), I want to copy a row and write it to a new CSV.

The thing is, I don't understand how to select rows in Pandas, I consulted the documentation, but it still puzzles me. I tried .loc and .ix but I think I'm doing it wrong. So my idea was to add rownumbers and then index on the basis of these rownumbers using a counter and .ix. Since my index is thus an integer, I figured this might work:

```
selectRow = file_df.ix[counter,:]
```

except it doesn't. Any tips on how to select an entire row? I'm probably missing something super easy.

Total code:
    # Script takes tweets and selects retweets, printing the entire row to a new file.

```
import pandas as pd
import string

print("Loading file & initializing variables.")

# load file
file_df = pd.read_csv("Desktop/tweetsamples.csv", delimiter=";")

#declare stuff we need to use
output_df = pd.DataFrame()
rowToCopy = pd.Series()
selectRow = pd.Series()
withoutPuncSeries = pd.Series()
counter = 0
retweet = False
username = ""

print("Working.. Please be patient.")

# define for loop which checks if there is a retweet in the tweet

content = file_df["header"] 

splitContent = [content.str.split()] #initialize list
for wordsLists in splitContent:
    counter = counter + 1
    for wordsList in wordsLists:
        if wordsList[0] == "RT":
            retweet = True
            username = wordsList[1]
            withoutPunctuation = "" #initialize/reset placeholder string
            for char in username: #we want to get rid of potential interpunction errors behind the username, so we loop through the string
                if char != "@": #we don't want to have the @
                    if char == "_" or char not in string.punctuation: #only desired characters ('_' is a valid char in an username)
                        withoutPunctuation = withoutPunctuation + char.lower() #add to placeholder string
            print "Found retweet from:", withoutPunctuation
            withoutPuncSeries = [withoutPunctuation]
            selectRow = file_df.ix[counter,:]

    rowToCopy = [selectRow, withoutPuncSeries]
    output_df = output_df.append(rowToCopy) 
    rowToCopy = pd.Series() #reset
    withoutPuncSeries = pd.Series()

output_df.to_csv("Desktop/retweet test.csv", sep=";")

print("Done.")
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: How are you looking to select the entire row?

Answer (score 0):

you can select a single row with `df.iloc[row]` or a range with `df.iloc[startrow:endrow]`. In your case there is a extra comma that seems to make problems.

Comment: Both of the above can be used to select single/multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select rows based on a condition, something like this should work.

```
def my_function(header):
    if header[0]=='RT': #or whatever your condition is
        return True
    else:
        return False


df_new = df[df['header'].apply(my_function)]
df_new.to_csv('../only_rt.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is Boolean masking, the problem is the data structure is not very clear. `pandas` has a lot of functions that operate on strings such as `contains`, `startswith`,..etc

```
retweet_df = file_df[file_df['header'].str.contains('RT') & ....]
```

Boolean masks can contain multiple statements combined through the logical operators `&` (and),`|` (or) `~`(not)